# on product gallery lineup - making the short excerpt a minimum length

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

*This is for the woocommerce plugin running on wordpress*

I would like to make all the product description parts have a **minimum** height so that the buttons all line up after the excerpts.

this is part of the php that calls that excerpt text :

```
function woo_show_excerpt_shop_page() {
global $product;
echo $product->post->post_excerpt;
```

but i don't know how to style it!

See the image:

[image: product descriptions]

any help would be awesome

here's a page with the issue : https://pensteel.co.uk/product-category/ibcs-accessories/ibcs-accessories-spares/

Comment: Can't you just make both divs have the same height? You can do so with Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

This way if an excerpt is shorter, there will be some white space from the end of the text to the button, but all buttons will line up.

Comment: i'm honestly not sure where the divs are that create this part of the page. 

i was hoping i could span the post_excerpt with something like this :

 `echo "<span class=\"excerpt\">$product->post->post_excerpt</span>";`

but it fails

Comment: Use flexbox layout